# d20 system mechanics in Godot

Tags: godot

I'm having trouble with the code below. The attacker is doing two rounds before reversing the turn, and the correct thing is to have a round of attack and alternate. Another detail is that the 'for' doesn't seem to be working... it gets information on how much dice the player has, but for some reason, the 'print' I put doesn't return 2 values (for example, for a player with two dice). I believe there is a lot to improve, creating more functions, but I am a beginner.

**AutoLoad**:

```
extends Node2D

var enemy_turn : bool = false
var critical_Hit : bool = false

func _start_combat(player, enemy):
    if enemy_turn == false:
        turn(enemy, player)
    else:
        turn(player, enemy)

func roll(dice) -> int:
    var random_number = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
    random_number.randomize()
    return random_number.randi_range(1, dice)

func turn(target, attacker):
    print(attacker.char_name, " attack ", target.char_name)
    var iniciative_roll = roll(20)
    print("Iniciative d20: ", iniciative_roll)
    
    if iniciative_roll == 20:
        print("Critical Hit!") #Tenho que verificar se eu estou saindo daqui sem passar para baixo visto que 20 >= abs()
        critical_Hit = true
    elif iniciative_roll >= abs(target.ac - attacker.thac0):
        critical_Hit = false
    else:
        print(attacker.char_name, " miss.")
        enemy_turn =! enemy_turn
        _start_combat(attacker,target)
        return
    
    var dmg_roll : int = 0
    for n in attacker.row:
        dmg_roll += roll(attacker.dice)
        print(dmg_roll)
        return damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll)
        
func damage(target, attacker, aux):
    if critical_Hit == true:
        target.hp -= 2 * aux
    else:
        target.hp -= aux
    print(attacker.char_name, " do ", aux, " damage ", target.char_name)
    
    if target.hp <= 0:
        target._death()
    else:
        enemy_turn =! enemy_turn
        _start_combat(attacker,target)
```

Taking advantage, can the arguments that a function receives be the same as the variables sent? Is this not very ugly or wrong? Ex:

```
func turn(target, attacker):
    ...
        return damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll)
        
func damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll):
    ...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The attacker is doing two rounds before reversing the turn, and the correct thing is to have a round of attack and alternate.

Have another look at this code:

```
func _start_combat(player, enemy):
    if enemy_turn == false:
        turn(enemy, player)
    else:
        turn(player, enemy)
```

It will flip the order of the arguments of `turn` depending on `enemy_turn`.

The parameters of `turn` are like this:

```
func turn(target, attacker):
```

And then they do this:

```
enemy_turn =! enemy_turn
_start_combat(attacker,target)
```

Remember that `enemy_turn` controls if `_start_combat` flips the arguments or not. But also notice you are calling `_start_combat` with the arguments flipped. So there is always a flip, but depending on `enemy_turn` there is an extra flip… And the flips cancels out resulting in a repeated turn.

---

There is an extra wrinkle in that `damage` does the same thing that `turn` does:

```
enemy_turn =! enemy_turn
_start_combat(attacker,target)
```

This is the logic we need to change, and preferably we want to change it in a single place. A single source of truth of how to change turns.

You should refactor repetition out of `damage`. Furthermore…

---

I believe you want to have `turn` not be concerned with the order. *Otherwise you would have put the logic you have in `_start_combat` inside of `turn`.* Thus, don't have `turn` be concerned with the order at all! It should not be manipulating `enemy_turn =! enemy_turn`. In fact, it should not be calling `_start_combat`.

So we are separating these two concerns:

- How to switch turns
- How to execute turns

To do that we would put the logic of switching turn in `_start_combat`. It can have a loop where it calls `turn` one way, and then the other. Ah, but that reveals that we need to extract the end of combat logic.

Currently you are not having an stack overflow because combat is short enough. But your stack will be calls to `_start_combat` that call `turn` that call `_start_combat` that call `turn` that call `_start_combat` and so on.

Currently the end of combat logic is in `damamge`:

```
if target.hp <= 0:
    target._death()
```

It ends combat by not calling `_start_combat` again.

---

So you can do something like this:

```
func _start_combat(player, enemy):
    var target
    var attacker
    while true:
        if enemy_turn == false:
            target = enemy
            attacker = player
        else:
            target = player
            attacker = enemy

        turn(target, attacker)
        if target.hp <= 0:
            target._death()
            break
```

**EDIT**: In the above code I forgot to change `enemy_turn`. It should be in the loop:

```
func _start_combat(player, enemy):
    var target
    var attacker
    while true:
        if enemy_turn == false:
            target = enemy
            attacker = player
        else:
            target = player
            attacker = enemy

        turn(target, attacker)
        if target.hp <= 0:
            target._death()
            break

        enemy_turn =! enemy_turn
```

Then `damage` can be just this:

```
func damage(target, attacker, aux):
    if critical_Hit == true:
        target.hp -= 2 * aux
    else:
        target.hp -= aux
    print(attacker.char_name, " do ", aux, " damage ", target.char_name)
```

And remove these from `turn` too:

```
enemy_turn =! enemy_turn
_start_combat(attacker,target)
```

---

I can tell you right now that the above code likely won't stand in the long run. Presumably you want to add animations, sound effects, or similar... Or simply wait for user input. Then you want to use `yield`. And if `yield` you problems (and it might) I will strongly encourage looking into using signals instead of method calls. You can define your own signals, emit them, connect methods to them. *That is not for this answer, just something you might want to look into.*

---

Ok, the other thing:

> Another detail is that the 'for' doesn't seem to be working

Look here you are returning on the first iteration:

```
for n in attacker.row:
    dmg_roll += roll(attacker.dice)
    print(dmg_roll)
    return damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll)
```

My intuition would be to call `damage` to be outside of the loop:

```
for n in attacker.row:
    dmg_roll += roll(attacker.dice)
    print(dmg_roll)

return damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll)
```

In fact, `damage` does not return, and you don't use the return value of `turn`, so you could also remove the `return` keyword…

```
for n in attacker.row:
    dmg_roll += roll(attacker.dice)
    print(dmg_roll)

damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll)
```

So if you actually meant to call `damage` in a loop, you can also do that:

```
for n in attacker.row:
    dmg_roll += roll(attacker.dice)
    print(dmg_roll)
    damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your comment and attention, you are very didactic.
I'm going to comment my post with the change and unfortunately ''it didn't happen'' what I believe you and I expected.

Comment: @MarceloJoão I see, I didn't include `enemy_turn =! enemy_turn`, it would go in the loop. I'll edit my answer with that. Edit: done.

Comment: Thank you very much. The code worked! The only detail I noticed is that when the critical damage happened, he didn't double the damage. I haven't tried to figure it out yet, but I will.

Comment: U can see the log here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CQWwdZg_giI56dwSze-sQc7uwNEjrXCR/view?usp=share_link There were two snakes in the scene.

Comment: @MarceloJoão Part of it is that the variables `enemy_turn` and `critical_Hit` keep their value between calls. You could declare them in the method that use them (for `critical_Hit` in `damage` you could pass it as parameter from `turn`). I don't know about the repeated turns. How does your code look like after the changes?

Comment: I made a mistake with the indentation of the code. 
The code was correct. I woke up very early and my head woke up a little slow. LOL

Comment: I just want to take advantage of your knowledge a little more. My intention is that in fact the combat happens instantly, but since the `yield` is not very recommended, I can use a `timeout signal` in case I want to ''slow down a little'', for example, to make a shaking animation or even visually present what damage was generated between combat?

Comment: @MarceloJoão The problem with `yield` is that it does not disconnect when you `free` (or `queue_free`) the `Node`s, which results in a runtime error, because it tries to resume code on an object that has been freed. But if you explicitly `connect` methods, they do disconnect. If you are sure that the `Node`s won't be freed early, then there is no problem using `yield`.  With that said, `yield` works with signals, for example `yield(timer, "timeout")`. However, find the signals that make sense, for example if you have an `AnimationPlayer` use `animation_finished`.

Answer (score 0):

```
extends Node2D

var enemy_turn : bool = false
var critical_Hit : bool = false

func _start_combat(player, enemy):
    var target
    var attacker
    while true:
        if enemy_turn == false:
            target = enemy
            attacker = player
        else:
            target = player
            attacker = enemy
            
        turn(target, attacker)
        if target.hp <= 0:
            target._death()
            break

func roll(dice) -> int:
    var random_number = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
    random_number.randomize()
    return random_number.randi_range(1, dice)

func turn(target, attacker):
    print(attacker.char_name, " atack ", target.char_name)
    var iniciative_roll = roll(20)
    print("Iniciative d20: ", iniciative_roll)
    
    if iniciative_roll == 20:
        print("Critical Hit!") #Tenho que verificar se eu estou saindo daqui sem passar para baixo visto que 20 >= abs()
        critical_Hit = true
    elif iniciative_roll >= abs(target.ac - attacker.thac0):
        critical_Hit = false
    else:
        print(attacker.char_name, " miss.")
        return
    
    var dmg_roll : int = 0
    for n in attacker.row:
        dmg_roll += roll(attacker.dice)
        print(dmg_roll)
        
    damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll)
        
func damage(target, attacker, dmg_roll):
    if critical_Hit == true:
        target.hp -= 2 * dmg_roll
    else:
        target.hp -= dmg_roll
    print(attacker.char_name, " do ", dmg_roll, " damage ", target.char_name)
```

See the DEBUG:

```
Player made an attack action...
Jobson atack Globin
Iniciative d20: 2
Jobson miss.
Jobson atack Globin
Iniciative d20: 16
10
Jobson do 10 damage Globin
Jobson atack Globin
Iniciative d20: 5
Jobson miss.
Jobson atack Globin
Iniciative d20: 13
16
Jobson do 16 damage Globin
Globin DIE!
```

He didn't reverse the turn.
And the curious thing is that precisely, the action occurs instantly. LOL
I didn't think to get around it for now. `yield` it doesn't seem good to use, it seems to give a lot of bugs.

Comment: I put the code `enemy_turn =! enemy_turn` / `_start_combat(attacker,target)` at the end of the damage function, it reverses, but it didn't look good. Even the player missing the attack, it goes to the damage step. And, even after one of the opponents is eliminated, the game continues to iterate.

Comment: I don't know what is up with it going from missing to damage. I'm going to suggest to add a `breakpoint` and then advance step by step to see what is going on. Anyway, I have edited my answer. And, to reiterate, look into using signals.